# How to pass a list as extra variable in Ansible CLI?

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to override an Ansible variable by passing it as an `--extra-var`/`-e` from the CLI.  The catch is that the variable I want to override is a list and I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Here's what the variable looks like in my `group_vars` file:

```
my_variable:
    - { var1: "value1", var2: "value2" }
    ...
```

Here's what my command looks like:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e 'my_variable={ var1: value1, var2: value2 }' --limit 1.2.3.4 --diff --check
```

I get the following error:

> fatal: [1.2.3.4] => with_items expects a list or a set

Is this possible?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's actually quite an unusual error - with the command you posted, you are defining `my_variable` as a one-character string (`{`) and strings are iterable with `with_items`. Elements will be individual characters (in this case there's only one anyway), so further processing might fail, but it shouldn't result in the error you posted. Sorry, but this question is a mess. You should already know to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example), so you need to enclose your dictionary in square brackets to be passed as an element of a list (an *array* in JSON parlance). Moreover, you need to quote it properly:

```
-e 'my_variable="[ { \"var1\": \"value1\", \"value2\": \"value2\" } ]"'
```